# Como inserir o retorno do erro numa parte específica do html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parcelas').on('change', function(){
        var parcela = this.value;
        var entrada = document.getElementsByName("entrada")[0].value;
        $("#bodyBoletos").html("");
        divida_id = {{$divida->id}};
        $.ajax({
        url:"/dashboard/admin/negociacao/parcelamento/"+divida_id+"/"+parcela+"/"+entrada,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){


            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var numero = response[i].numero;
                var vencimento = response[i].vencimento;
                var valor = response[i].valor;


                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + numero + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + vencimento + "</td>" +
                    "<td>R$ " +formatMoney(valor) + "</td>" +

                    "</tr>";

                $("#boletos tbody").append(tr_str);
            }

        },error: function (data) {

                    var html = '';
                    if(data.errors)
                    {
                    html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
                    {
                    html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
                    }
                    html += '</div>';
                    $('#form_result').html(html);
                    }
                }

    });
```

HTML

```
  <span id="form_result"> ...erros aqui... </span>
```

Comment: Ola @andré, vi que você esta tentando inserir os erros no html de dentro da *callback error* do ajax (`,error: function (data){`), acho que talvez esse seja seu problema, normalmente essa *callback* é executa quando ocorre algo errado com o request *(Ex.: Not Found, Internal Server Error, blocked by CORS, sem internet, parsererror, ...)*, se você esta retornando um json com erros ele deve esta chegando na *success*.

Comment: É isso mesmo, coloquei  junto do success e ajustei o retorno no php e deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse no [comentário da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/404049/como-inserir-o-retorno-do-erro-numa-parte-espec%c3%adfica-do-html?noredirect=1#comment792065_404049), estava certo a forma que você selecionava o elemento e adicionava o texto HTML `$('#form_result').html(html);`, o problema estava no fato desse código esta sendo chamado dentro da *callback `error:function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`* do `$.ajax`, uma vez que normalmente essa *callback* só é chamada quando ocorre uma **falha na requisição**, como por exemplo: *Not Found*, *Internal Server Error*, *blocked by CORS*, *parsererror*, *no internet connection*, etc...

E como pelo visto seu serviço estava retornando um JSON com erros, ele estaria chegando na *callback `success:function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`*

> **[`jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)**
>
> **error:**
>
> Type: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`
>   **A function to be called if the request fails.**
>   The function receives three arguments:
>
> 1. The **jqXHR** *(in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest)* object
> 2. **A string** describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.
>      *Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are `"timeout"`, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and `"parsererror"`.*
> 3. When an HTTP error occurs, `errorThrown` receives the **textual portion of the HTTP status**, such as `"Not Found"` or `"Internal Server Error."`